# RouterLink Works in Browser But Not on Emulator or Device

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, routerlink, angular11

On my homepage, I have a routerlink to a more detailed movie page:

```
<ion-col class="ion-text-left"  [routerLink]="['/item-details/', title.imdbid]" routerDirection="forward">
...
</ion-col>
```

and this is how item id is being read in details page.ts onNgInit method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeVariation = 'size';
    this.imdbId = this.route.snapshot.params.imdbId;
    console.log(this.imdbId);
    this.title = this.data.getDetailsByImdbId(this.imdbId).subscribe(
      (res) => this.title = res,
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.error(this.title)
    );    
  }
```

and this is how it's shown in the page.html:

```
<h1 class="item-name"> {{ title.Title }}</h1>
```

Everything is working perfectly fine in the browser when I run:

```
ionic serve
```

But when I run the application on the device or in an emulator, all the title.xxx elements in the details page are blank.

When I debug it, I can get the app to log "title.Title" correctly from ngOnInit method in the emulator, but it still won't show on the page. It's almost like ngOnInit finishes after the page loads, but when the title is not undefined anymore, the page doesn't get updated.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

---

Try using an [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
<h1 class="item-name">  {{(title| async)?.Title}}</h1>
```

This should do the trick, also. Don't reuse the subscruption, In edge cases it can be bad. I normally suggest using `ngOnDestroy` and unsubscribe.

Change your ts file to this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeVariation = 'size';
    this.imdbId = this.route.snapshot.params.imdbId;
    console.log(this.imdbId);
    this.title = this.data.getDetailsByImdbId(this.imdbId) //this returns an observable
      }
    
     ngOnDestroy() {
        this.title.unsubscribe();
      }
```

Maybe also consider not using a snapshot and using a pipe instead

```
     this.title = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
switchMap((params) => {
      this.imdbId = params.get('imdbId');
      return this.data.getDetailsByImdbId(this.imdbId)
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
);
```

But I might have written the code wrong, that's why I am editing it in, if someone is certain, they can correct me.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Anant, but it still has the same problem. Your changes work in the browser, but not on the device/emulator. I feel like it's something completely unrelated to how the data is being retrieved, but how it's tried to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The actual problem was not that routerLink wasn't working, but the data wasn't being fetched by the data service (bad error handling :/). I didn't suspect that it could be the case because because my API calls were working fine in Postman.

Nonetheless, I had to allow the application to use clear text traffic by adding the below to AndroidManifest.xml file, and all is fine now.

```
<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```